# Detect encryption method

Tags: encryption, decryption

So I was doing some research and struck at some point where the server generate a token to the client and further communications are using this token from client. So can somebody let me know what encryption method the below text uses?

```
hh72daDJ74s=
```

Comment: "What encryption is used in this random string" is the kind of question that is off-topic here. We can't answer a thousand instances of this as it is irrelevant to anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

That is just a bunch of bytes, it could be anything, most likely a random token. The thing you posted is (most likely) a base64 encoded version of some bunch of bytes. If you decode it, you get some 8 random bytes. The only thing that tells is is that if it is indeed the output of some cipher, then either the cipher has a block size of 64bits (i.e. it can't be AES), or its used in streaming mode (e.g. [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29)).

Here's how you see the token's value:

```
$ echo 'hh72daDJ74s=' | base64 -d | hexdump -C
00000000  86 1e f6 75 a0 c9 ef 8b                           |...u....|
```